# how to get the edited textarea data in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

am using tinymce to edit the data. am able to edit the data but how to get that data inorder to post it and update database in codeigniter. on clicking the submit button i need to get the data which is edited need to update in database. can someone help me please. thanks. the code is as follows

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><textarea><?php echo $_GET['content_s_no'];?> </textarea></td>
<td><textarea><?php echo $_GET['content'];?></textarea> </td>
<td><input type="button">submit</></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

Comment: Not relevant to CodeIgniter. Just google HTML Forms and HTTP Post method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="YOUR/CONTROLLER/FUNCTION" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><textarea name="txt1"><?php echo $_GET['content_s_no'];?> </textarea></td>
<td><textarea name="txt2"><?php echo $_GET['content'];?></textarea> </td>
<td><button type="submit">submit</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){      
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
});
</script>
```

---

I guess, you need this too.

in your controller/function.

```
if($this->input->post()){
  $txt1 = $this->input->post('txt1');
  $txt2 = $this->input->post('txt2');
  $this->db->update('your_table',array(
     'txt1' => $txt1,
     'txt2' => $txt2
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: if on clicking submit button if i need to see the edited data how to get that

Comment: example for getting the submitted data from textarea name=txt1: <?=$this->input->post('txt1');?>

Comment: if you are using form validation lib, you can use <?=set_value('txt1');?>

Comment: i need to check whether the data after editing is getting or not so. how to check that can i use like alert('txt1'); or any other method

Comment: in PHP, you can use var_dump($var);

Comment: it's the same as using echo. in your <?php var_dump($variable);?>

Comment: hi mar can you help me that in controller am getting value i want to update the database in model. how to do that.function edit_data()
 { 
       $txt2 = $this->input->post('txt2');  
       echo $txt2;exit;

 }